# Adding items to a Sencha Tab panel dynamically

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, extjs

How can I add items to a Sencha Tab Panel in runtime. I used add() function but it is not working?

Thanks
Arun A G

Comment: The add() method should do exactly what you want. Can you post the code you are using that isn't working?

Comment: thanks stuart i have used add() method in wrong format and now it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all, those who replied and those who viewed .

The problem is solved with the add() method itself. Actually I was using it in wrong format ie
myTab.items.add(newItem);

You just have call the method add() within myTab's scope. ie
myTab.add(newItem);

Answer (score 0):

How are you invoking add()? Can you edit your post to include the code in question?

You can also do something like this...

```
    Ext.apply(myTabPanel, {
        items: [
            item1,
            item2,
            item3
        ]
    });
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: hi Old McStopher, I have solved the issue with add() method. Initially I have used it in wrong format... thanks for your response. I have to add the panel tabs each time we login(dynamically) so we can't use your code. Any way thanks